# JPA reference table mapping

Tags: java, jpa, one-to-many

There are two main `@Entity` classes reflecting these tables:

```
TableA {id,name}
TableB {id,name}
```

And one reference table

```
TableC {tableA.id,tableB.id}
```

Question is: how to map a `TableA`'s entity's field with `@OneToMany` realation to TableB objects list:

```
@OneToMany
??????????
private List<TableBEntity> tableBItems;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you really have is a OneToMany (which means that a give `tableB.id` appears at most once in `TableC`), then the mapping is the following:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinTable(name = "TableC",
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "TABLE_A_ID"),
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "TABLE_B_ID"))
private List<TableBEntity> tableBItems;
```

Else, what you have is in fact a ManyToMany, and the mapping is the same, except that `@OneToMany` must be replaced by `@ManyToMany`.