# JPA: How to model Map<String, Set<Object>> (nested collection)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, collections, nested

this question is related to 
[Is it possible to map a map<String,List<Entity>> in JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9784101/is-it-possible-to-map-a-mapstring-listentity-in-jpa) but unfortunately the top-rated answer wasn't much helpful.

Also the related article http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Nested_Collections.2C_Maps_and_Matrices captures a different use case as the main entity is related to the MapKey (ProjectType).

In my use case a company uses multiple accounts. The accounts should be grouped by the TYPE of usage (called AccountType). So what I want in CompanyEntity is basically something like

```
@MapKeyColumn(name = "TYPE")
@MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.STRING)
//Missing JPA-Magic
private Map<AccountType, Set<AccountEntity>> accounts;
```

My data model: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MORgD.png

How can I achieve this mapping in the most elegant way?

Many thanks upfront!

Comment: The related article explains all you need to know ... split the "List" out into a separate intermediate type, and then you have a Map with values of an Entity type. The same applies to your data

Answer (score 1):

Well you can create an object containing you set of AccountEntity like:

```
public class Accounts{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private long id;

  @Column(name="ACC_TYPE")
  private String type;


  @ManyToMany
  private Set<AccountEntity> accounts;
}
```

And then have your CompanyEntity:

```
@MapKeyColumn(name = "TYPE")
@MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Map<AccountType, Accounts accounts;
```

Comment: The bottom line seems to be missing a closing bracket

Answer (score -1):

Here's an answer how to manage a **reference table** in JPA:

[JPA reference table mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11466593/jpa-reference-table-mapping)